# How can I get the web browser toolbar option back in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I had to set up a new environment and now the web browser toolbar button is missing.  It used to look like this...

[image: Old setup]

But now it looks like this...

[image: New Setup]

I cannot find that Web Browser button anywhere.  It must be part of the standard toolbar but I cannot find it.

Comment: I still don't have this fixed.  My Angular / Razor project shows the correct toolbar but my webapi project does not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Visual Studio 16.6.1 patch fixed the issue.